# VBA : How to delete a file?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there VBA code that can delete Excel files?

Any help or example would be welcome.

Comment: What bin? the recycle bin? [To the Bin](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/recycle.aspx)

Comment: I believe so. I don't know exactly in English. But I want to automatically throw away various files so they will be deleted when I will empty the bin.

Comment: See the link in my previous post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is something I use. Very clean and effective:

```
Sub DeleteTEMPIMPORTWorkbook()

    Dim MyDir As String, fn As String
    MyDir = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments") & "\My Files" ' Change this to the directory where the file you need to delete is located.

    On Error Resume Next
    Kill MyDir & "\TEMPIMPORT.xlsx"
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Please note, using `Kill` does **NOT** send the file to the Recycle Bin. It will permanently delete the file.

Comment: @Studix You're welcome. If the answer worked, please upvote the answer.